# How do I update the incoming value if it's a photo? [LARAVEL 9]

Tags: php, laravel, database

i have a question.

**database settings table :** [image]

**When adding a new setting I am sending data like this :**

```
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tip</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="type">
                    <option value="text">Kısa yazı</option>
                    <option value="file">Dosya (Resim vb.)</option>
                    <option value="textarea">Uzun yazı</option>
                    <option value="ckeditor">Detaylı Metin Editörü</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

**and I'm querying this while editing:**

```
              @if ($setting->type == 'file')
                    <div class="form-group">
                <img width="200" height="100" src="{{ asset('storage/' . $setting->value) }}">                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" name="value" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Açıklama:</label>
                @endif
```

**update method:**

```
 public function update(Request $request, Setting $setting)
{
    $request->validate([
        'key' => 'required',
        'value' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);




    $setting->update([
        'key' => $request->key,
        'value' => $request->value,
        'type' => $request->type,
        'description' => $request->description,

    ]);




    return redirect()->route('admin.settings.index')->with('message', 'Ayar başarıyla güncellendi.');
}
```

**my question is: if value part is photo how can i update it as photo...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UploadedFile`'s **store** or **storeAs** to store the uploaded file and then store the file path as **value** in the database.

And don't forget to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form

```php
public function update(Request $request, Setting $setting)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'key' => 'required',
        'value' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('value') && $request->file('value')->isValid() ){
        $validated['value'] = $request->file('value')->store('/files', 'public');
    }


    $setting->update($validated);




    return redirect()->route('admin.settings.index')->with('message', 'Ayar başarıyla güncellendi.');
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Request - Files](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#files)

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I solved my problem, it was a bit of a simple question, sorry
**

```
    public function update(Request $request, Setting $setting)
{
    $request->validate([
        'key' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $value = $setting->value;
    if ($request->type == 'file') {
        $value = $request->file('value')->store('public/settings');
    } else {
        $value = $request->value;
    }

    $setting->update([
        'key' => $request->key,
        'type' => $request->type,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'value' => $value,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings.index')->with('message', 'Ayar başarıyla güncellendi.');
}
```